# Custom metrics that relies on additional features in training data

Tags: r, tidymodels

How can I implement a custom metric that relies on additional features in training data? Below is an example for within R Squared with additional code reproduce the core issue. The implementation uses an additional argument called `group` for the name of the grouping variable. This implementation works when I call it directly and pass the entire training data to the `data` argument with an additional column for `estimate`. More precisely, the `tibble` passed to the `data` argument needs three columns for `truth`, `estimate`, and `group`.

However, this approach does not work with any of the tuning functions such as `tune_grid` or `workflow_map` because these functions only pass a `data.frame` with three variables to any metric function: `.pred`, `.row` and the observed values `truth`.

How can I implement a custom metric that requires additional columns from the training data?

```
# Custom metric --------------------------------------------------------------
rsq_within_vec <- function(truth, estimate, group, na_rm = TRUE, ...) {

  rsq_within_impl <- function(truth, estimate, group) {
    d <- tibble(truth, estimate, group) %>%
      group_by(group) %>%
      mutate(truth = truth - mean(truth), estimate = estimate - mean(estimate))
    if(sd(d$estimate) == 0) return(0)
    yardstick:::yardstick_cor(d$truth, d$estimate)^2
  }

  metric_vec_template(
    metric_impl = rsq_within_impl,
    truth = truth, 
    estimate = estimate,
    na_rm = na_rm,
    cls = "numeric",
    group = group,
    ...
  )
  
}

rsq_within <- function(data, ...) {
  UseMethod("rsq_within")
}

rsq_within <- new_numeric_metric(rsq_within, direction = "maximize")

rsq_within.data.frame <- function(data, truth, estimate, group, na_rm = TRUE, ...) {
  numeric_metric_summarizer(
    name = "rsq_within",
    fn = rsq_within_vec,
    data = data,
    truth = !! enquo(truth),
    estimate = !! enquo(estimate),
    fn_options = list(group = select(data, !! enquo(group))[[1]]),
    na_rm = na_rm,
    ...
  )
}

# Wrapper --------------------------------------------------------------
rsq_within_gear <- function(data, truth, estimate, na_rm = TRUE, ...) {
  rsq_within(
    data = data,
    truth = !!rlang::enquo(truth),
    estimate = !!rlang::enquo(estimate),
    group = gear,
    na_rm = na_rm,
    ...
  )
}

rsq_within_gear <- new_numeric_metric(rsq_within_gear, direction = "maximize")


# Illustrate problem with example -----------------------------------------------------
set.seed(6735)
folds <- vfold_cv(mtcars, v = 5)

recipe <- recipes::recipe(mpg ~ cyl, data = head(mtcars))
model <- linear_reg() %>% set_engine("lm")
wf <- workflow() %>% add_recipe(recipe) %>% add_model(model)

# Does not work
tune_grid(
    object    = wf,
    resamples = folds,
    grid      = 1,
    metrics   = metric_set(rmse, rsq, rsq_within_gear)
) %>%
collect_metrics()
```

Comment: I think you're exactly right about the current situation. I recommend that you check out what the [waywiser](https://github.com/ropensci/waywiser) package does about this, and chime in [on this issue](https://github.com/tidymodels/tune/issues/522) about your use case.